# Direct link for application updated version in AppStore

Tags: ios, app-store, hyperlink

Within my application there is alink to to appstore for downloading the new version of my application.
When user press this link, the iPhone open some screes before getting the AppStore screen.
Those screen, seem to be the browser's screens, but i'm not sure.
How can i create a direct link to my application in AppStore?
Thanks,
Eyal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/APPNAME
```

Example:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/trenes"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```